# How to set fixed aspect ratio view inside parent in UWP and can stretch uniform when resize window?

Tags: uwp, user-controls, aspect-ratio

I want set the DropShadowPanel width and height is depend on its parent when still keep aspect ratio.

```
<Grid Background="White" Padding="10,10,10,10">

    <controls:DropShadowPanel Color="Black"
                      BlurRadius="30"
                      ShadowOpacity=".7"
                      Width="200" Height="300"                          
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                                          
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

When resize the window (resize grid parent), its width or height will change to maximum value.
How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set fixed aspect ratio view inside parent in UWP and can stretch uniform when resize window?

For your requirement, we suggest you insert  `DropShadowPanel` into [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-19041), it is a container control that scales its content to a specified size.

```
<Grid Padding="10,10,10,10" Background="White">
    <Viewbox>
        <controls:DropShadowPanel
            Width="200"
            Height="300"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            BlurRadius="30"
            ShadowOpacity=".7"
            Color="Black">
            <Grid />
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Because inside <Grid /> I will add a drawing panel. If Viewbox scales its content, the drawing won't redraw and will be blurred. So what event will happen when the ViewBox changes its children size?

Comment: You could detect ViewBox Sizechanged event,